# Play / pause Vimeo Video when watcher switches browser tab or minimize browser window

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, vimeo

I'm using Vimeo Pro to upload video courses on a Wordpress Website and then, I use H5P to add interactions to the video.

In order to insert these vimeo videos in H5P Interactive Videos I need to use the .mp4 distribution of Vimeo Pro (and not the Vimeo Iframe). This is an example:

https://player.vimeo.com/external/376040732.sd.mp4?s=a88abddb83ad31962643b6c4dd8270323d80874e&profile_id=165

---

**ON THE WEBSITE**

If I inspect my website, this is the code:

```
<div class="h5p-video-wrapper h5p-video hardware-accelerated">

<video src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/376040732.sd.mp4?s=a88abddb83ad31962643b6c4dd8270323d80874e&amp;profile_id=165" webkit-playsinline="" playsinline="" preload="metadata" disableremoteplayback="" class="h5p-video" style="display: block;">
</video>
<div class="h5p-overlay h5p-ie-transparent-background"></div>

</div>
```

---

**MY REQUEST**

Which is the simplest method to pause the video when students switches the browser tab or minimize browser window? Thanks for your help!

**EDIT - SOLUTION**

Both Matt Oestreich's and Oliver Tacke's scripts works if you insert **only one H5P Interactive Video** in a webpage.

NB: If you need to insert **more than one H5P Interactive Video** in a webpage, use the Matt Oestreich's script.

Comment: I went ahead and figured out how to do this regardless of what the ID's are or how many of them there are... please see my updated answer.

Comment: We have it! I updated the question with solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [***YOU CAN FIND THE LIVE DEMO SITE HERE***](https://oze4.github.io/video-in-iframe/)
- [You can find all of the necessary code that was used here](https://github.com/oze4/video-in-iframe/blob/master/index.html)..
- [OP's live website where this is being used](https://www.sontraining.com/play-pause-h5p-video-iframe/)

---

---

***ANSWER:***

I had to clear out a lot of the previous updates, due to character limits in these answers.

I managed to get it working with multiple iframes..

*The only issue with this is if someone plays 2 different videos, then clicks on a different tab (pauses all videos) and they come back, it will play all videos... I can try to figure something out to resolve that, but for now this should do.*

Make sure to check out the updated demo site above as well..

Just put this script on any page that has a video you wish to pause/play using Page Visible API and the rest should take care of itself.

***You will need to use the following:***

```
const THE_IFRAME_SELECTOR = 'iframe[id^="h5p-iframe-"]'; // matches all iframes with an id that starts with h5p-iframe-
const THE_VIDEO_SELECTOR = 'video.h5p-video'; // since all videos appear to have the same class you don't need to change this
```

***Therefore, the new script should look like this:***

```
// ====================================================================================================================
// ~~~ SECOND SCRIPT ~~~ 
// THIS WAITS FOR THE IFRAME AND THE VIDEO INSIDE OF THE IFRAME TO BE CREATED BEFORE INITIALIZING THE PAGE VISIBLE API
// ====================================================================================================================
// "Global" variables.
const THE_IFRAME_SELECTOR = 'iframe[id^="h5p-iframe-"]'; // matches all iframes with an id that starts with h5p-iframe-
const THE_VIDEO_SELECTOR = 'video.h5p-video'; // since all videos appear to have the same class you don't need to change this

waitForMultipleElements(document, THE_IFRAME_SELECTOR, () => {
  let ALL_IFRAMES = document.querySelectorAll(THE_IFRAME_SELECTOR);
  ALL_IFRAMES.forEach(FOUND_IFRAME => {
    let FOUND_IFRAME_SELECTOR = `#${FOUND_IFRAME.id}`;
    console.log("FOUND_IFRAME_SELECTOR:", FOUND_IFRAME_SELECTOR)
    waitForElement(document, FOUND_IFRAME_SELECTOR, () => {
      waitForVideoElement(FOUND_IFRAME_SELECTOR, THE_VIDEO_SELECTOR, () => {
        initPageVisibleApi(FOUND_IFRAME_SELECTOR, THE_VIDEO_SELECTOR);
      });
    });
  });
});

function waitForMultipleElements(parentEl, selector, callback) {
  let theInterval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('still waiting for all elements: ' + selector);
    let elements = parentEl.querySelectorAll(selector);
    if (elements.length) {
      console.log("elements: " + selector + " exist!");
      clearInterval(theInterval);
      callback();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function waitForVideoElement(iframeSelector, videoElementSelector, callback) {
  let theIframeElement = document.querySelector(iframeSelector);
  let iframeEl = theIframeElement.contentWindow.document;
  waitForElement(iframeEl, videoElementSelector, () => {
    callback()
  });
}

function waitForElement(parentEl, selectorOfElementToWaitFor, callback) {
  let theInterval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log("still waiting for " + selectorOfElementToWaitFor);
    let element = parentEl.querySelector(selectorOfElementToWaitFor);
    if (element) {
      console.log(selectorOfElementToWaitFor + " exists!");
      clearInterval(theInterval);
      callback();
    }
  }, 100);
}

function initPageVisibleApi(iframeSelector, videoSelector) {
  // This is the same code that builds out the Page Visible API
  // event listeners. 
  // The only difference is I wrapped it in a function and added 
  // parameters to make it flexible.
  const iframe = document.querySelector(iframeSelector);
  const innerDoc = (iframe.contentDocument) ? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;
  const videoElement = innerDoc.querySelector(videoSelector);
  // Set the name of the hidden property and the change event for visibility
  var hidden, visibilityChange;
  if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") { // Opera 12.10 and Firefox 18 and later support 
    hidden = "hidden";
    visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
  } else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "msHidden";
    visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
  } else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "webkitHidden";
    visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
  }

  // To tell if video has been played yet or not
  let VIDEO_HAS_BEEN_PLAYED = false;
  // If the page is hidden, pause the video;
  // if the page is shown, play the video
  function handleVisibilityChange() {
    if (VIDEO_HAS_BEEN_PLAYED) {
      if (document[hidden]) {
        videoElement.pause();
      } else {
        videoElement.play();
      }
    }
  }
  // Warn if the browser doesn't support addEventListener or the Page Visibility API
  if (typeof document.addEventListener === "undefined" || hidden === undefined) {
    alert("This demo requires a browser, such as Google Chrome or Firefox, that supports the Page Visibility API.");
  } else {
    // Handle page visibility change   
    document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, handleVisibilityChange, false);

    // When the video pauses, set the title.
    // This shows the paused
    const defaultTitle = document.title;
    videoElement.addEventListener("pause", function () {
      document.title = 'Paused - ' + defaultTitle;
    }, false);
    // When the video plays, set the title.
    videoElement.addEventListener("play", function () {
      VIDEO_HAS_BEEN_PLAYED = true;
      document.title = 'Playing - ' + defaultTitle;
    }, false);
  }
}
// ====================================================================================================================
// ---------- END SECOND SCRIPT ------------
// ====================================================================================================================
```

Comment: Matt, I published a dedicated webpage to your script in my live website: 
https://www.sontraining.com/play-pause-h5p-video-iframe/

Can you please update my website link above in your answer? 
(this is because that webpage will not be available in the future) 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to amend H5P's functionality beyond a "hack", you should probably use the common way of customizing it. It usually makes thing much easier. Please see https://h5p.org/wordpress-customization for details.

Anyway, if you want to add some script inside your WordPress theme, this should do:

```
// This will only work for the first H5P IV found on the page!
// Since I don't know your environment, let's stick with ES5
var hidden, visibilityChange;
var interactiveVideo;
var currentState = -1;
var restartVideo = false;

/**
 * Handle change of page visibility.
 */
function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if ( ! interactiveVideo ) {
    return;
  }

  if ( document[hidden] ) {
    // There's nothing to do if the video isn't playing at all
    if ( 1 !== currentState ) {
      return;
    }

    restartVideo = true;
    interactiveVideo.pause();
  }
  else {
    // Restart if video was playing before
    if ( ! restartVideo ) {
      return;
    }

    restartVideo = false;
    interactiveVideo.play();
  }
}

/**
 * Add the stop/resume feature to video.
 * @param {Window} contentWindow Content Window containing H5P.
 */
function addVideoStopResume( contentWindow ) {
  // Set the name of the hidden property and the change event for visibility
  if ( 'undefined' !== typeof document.hidden ) { // Opera 12.10 and Firefox 18 and later support
    hidden = 'hidden';
    visibilityChange = 'visibilitychange';
  }
  else if ( 'undefined' !== typeof document.msHidden ) {
    hidden = 'msHidden';
    visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
  }
  else if ( 'undefined' !== typeof document.webkitHidden ) {
    hidden = 'webkitHidden';
    visibilityChange = 'webkitvisibilitychange';
  }

  // Get first instance of H5P.interactiveVideo -- will not work properly if there are more instances of IV!
  interactiveVideo = interactiveVideo || contentWindow.H5P.instances.filter( function ( instance ) {
    return instance.libraryInfo && 'H5P.InteractiveVideo' === instance.libraryInfo.machineName;
  })[0];

  if ( ! interactiveVideo ) {
    return;
  }

  // Remember current video state
  interactiveVideo.video.on('stateChange', function (state) {
    currentState = state.data;
  });

  if ( 'undefined' === typeof document.addEventListener || undefined === hidden ) {
    console.warn( 'The video stop/resume feature requires a browser, such as Google Chrome or Firefox, that supports the Page Visibility API.' );
  }
  else {
    // Handle page visibility change
    document.addEventListener( visibilityChange, handleVisibilityChange, false );
  }
}

/**
 * Initialize stop/resume feature.
 */
function initVideoStopResume() {
  var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName( 'iframe' );
  var i;
  var contentWindow;

  // Add EventListener if H5P content is present
  if ( 'complete' === document.readyState ) {
    for ( i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++ ) {

      // Skip non H5P iframes and remote iframes
      if ( ! iframes[i].classList.contains( 'h5p-iframe' ) &&
        (
          0 !== iframes[i].src.indexOf( window.location.origin ) ||
                    -1 === iframes[i].src.indexOf( 'action=h5p_embed' )
        )
      ) {
        continue;
      }

      // Edge needs to wait for iframe to be loaded, others don't
      contentWindow = iframes[i].contentWindow;
      if ( contentWindow.H5P ) {
        addVideoStopResume( contentWindow );
      }
      else {
        iframes[i].addEventListener( 'load', function () {
          contentWindow = this.contentWindow;
          addVideoStopResume( contentWindow );
        });
      }
    }
  }
}

// Amend content functionality when H5P content has loaded
if ( 'complete' === document.readyState ) {
  initVideoStopResume();
}
else {
  document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if ( 'complete' === document.readyState ) {
      initVideoStopResume();
    }
  };
}
```

The script will wait until the page has loaded and then traverse every H5P iframe on the page searching for an Interactive Video. It will then add the required functions to stop/resume a video on visibility changes.

*Please note that this solution will not work properly if you're using IVs inside other content types such as H5P Column. Also it will only work for the first Interactive Video on the page. Adding those features would require more code and were not requested.*

Comment: The issue is that the `document.readyState` *IS* `complete`, but the H5P `iframes` are not yet loaded. So this would not work. I tried this already. I even tried using the `iframe` loaded event, but that doesn't work either since `iframes` load a 'dummy' document as soon as they are added to the DOM (which is why I also wait for the actual video element to get created inside of the iframe [Check out this exaggerated demo](https://oze4.github.io/video-in-iframe/) - the document is ready but the iframes/video aren't.. [code is here](https://github.com/oze4/video-in-iframe/blob/master/index.html)

Comment: I'm not relying on the iframes' to be completely loaded. I'm not using the DOM's video instance, but the instance of H5P.Video that, to the best of my knowledge, should always be available as soon as the iframe is available.

Comment: Yea I know you're not.. and that's the problem.. Since H5P appears to programmatically add the video element to the iframe, you hit the document.readystate === 'complete' event before the videos are ready.. or else I would have just used that..Just to be safe, I check for the elements to make sure they exist first (iframe and video inside of it) before assigning Page Visible API.  Anyway, not like it really matters, and you don't have to take my word for it, but I've been blindly testing this with OP for like 2 days.

Comment: I just tested this on my 'exaggerated demo' and this code does not work for me. Although, it appears to work for OP (I'm not familiar at all with Wordpress or H5P so i had no clue if it would take 5ms or 5000ms to load up the necessary DOM elements - you seem to know more about how WP/H5P works than I do).. I figured it was best to make sure 100% these elements existed before assigning the Page Visible API..(seems like the iframes are in the DOM at 'readystate complete' for OP)

Comment: Do you really have to wait for the video DOM elements to be loaded if you call play() and pause() on the H5P.video instance?

Comment: Sorry, had not seen your 2nd answer when posting my reply. Your solution is definitely better as a general approach, but since the question explicitly stated H5P, my solution should be okay here.

Comment: Just to have a look to Oliver's script in action, I published a webpage where the Oliver's Script runs: 

https://www.sontraining.com/play-pause-h5p-video-iframe-olivers-script/

Comment: @Cornertip: I'm not proud of it though ;-) Matt's solution is a way more general approach. Checking iframes for H5P content is rather a hack as I mentioned. You could add custom JavaScript right inside the H5P iframe using the hooks offered by the H5P plugin (see my link above) and you could control any H5P.Video instance directly.

Comment: @OliverTacke actually a pretty good idea, too.. Keep in mind OP is admittedly not a developer, so this is something we'd have to show him how to accomplish. Thanks for your help, I see what you're doing now and it makes a lot of sense. Cheers!